# Mistake in the proof of Binet's formula

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I want to prove Binet's formula $F_{k} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\times\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k\right]$ for the $k_{th}$ fibonacci number.

I did as follows -

$F_{0}=0, F_{1} = 1$ .....

$F_{k} = F_{k-1}+F_{k-2}$

$F_kx^k=xF_{k-1}x^{k-1} + x^2F_{k-2}x^{k-2}$

summing over $k$ from $2$ to $\infty$,

$g(x)-1 = x(g(x)-1)+x^2g(x)\implies g(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-x-x^2} = \dfrac{-x}{x^2+x-1}$ where $g$ is the generating function of $F_0,F_1,F_2....$

Factoring we get

$g(x) = \dfrac{-x}{\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}
=-\left[\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(x-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(x-\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}\right]$

$\implies g(x) = -\left[\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)} + \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}\right] = \left[\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}-x\right)} + \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-x\right)}\right]$

$\implies g(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\dfrac{\frac{2}{1-\sqrt{5}}}{\left(1-\frac{2x}{1-\sqrt{5}}\right)}+\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot\dfrac{\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}}{\left(1-\frac{2x}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{2x}{1+\sqrt{5}}}-\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{2x}{1-\sqrt{5}}} \right]$

$\implies g(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^k-\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{2x}{1-\sqrt{5}}\right)^k\right] = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[\left(\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^k-\left(\dfrac{2}{1-\sqrt{5}}\right)^k\right]x^k$

$\\$

So I'm getting $F_k = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\times \left[\left(\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^k-\left(\dfrac{2}{1-\sqrt{5}}\right)^k\right]$ wheres actually $F_{k} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\times\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k\right]$.

Where did I go wrong? I cant figure it out. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.milefoot.com/math/discrete/sequences/binetformula.htm Are you doing anything different compared to this?

Comment: @AndrewChin The method in the link seems completely different to me. I do know how to arrive at the formula correctly using this method - https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula I was trying out various approaches but the when do the generating function, I get a flipped answer.

Comment: @AndrewChin In other sources, the factorization is done a bit differently as follows, $g(x) = \dfrac{A}{1-\phi x}+\dfrac{B}{1-\tau x}$ where $\phi$ and $\tau$ are the roots of the denominator of the generating fun. When factorized this way, the answer seems to come out correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the roots of $x^2+x-1$ are $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$, at the begining  it should be
$$g(x) = \dfrac{-x}{\left(x+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}.$$
and therefore, at the end, we find
$$F_k = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\times \left[\left(\dfrac{-2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^k-\left(\dfrac{-2}{1-\sqrt{5}}\right)^k\right].$$
We recover the classic Binet's formula, by noting that,
$$\frac{-2}{1+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1-\sqrt{5}}=
\frac{-2(1-\sqrt{5})}{1-5}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{-2}{1-\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-2}{1-\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}=
\frac{-2(1+\sqrt{5})}{1-5}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Comment: I think it should be $$
g(x) = \frac{{ - x}}{{\left( {x + \frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2}} \right)\left( {x - \frac{{ - 1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2}} \right)}}.$$

Comment: @Gary Thanks for pointing out.